# What is the correct plural of horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

We all know that there was more than one horcrux, so the word must have a plural form. But, what is the grammatically correct way to spell the term for "more than one horcrux"?

Comment: Well, since HP uses a lot of pseudo-latin, why not "horcrucies"?

Comment: you made the error you just saved someone else from doing and called harry a horcux!! :P

Comment: Or maybe, "[horcruxen](https://youtu.be/QWzYaZDK6Is?t=1m56s)"? He made a flock of horcruxen. Many much horcruxen. Out in the woodsen.

Comment: to be honest, the only reason I asked the question was to create the horcruz tag, which Richard deleted :(

Comment: @KSmarts Wouldn't it be "horcruces" in Latin?

Comment: Break the word down into its prefix/suffix pair and it would be hor - crux, the plural of crux is cruxes or cruces.

Comment: yeah, I don't see how anyone gets "horcri" at all. The singular of horcri would be horcr**us**.

Comment: @user14111 with Latin loan words in English, it's a toss-up if you use Latin or English pluralization rule. The question was originally a joke -- horcruxes is the right answer because it's in the book and is a legitimate plural -- but Richard's answer is so good I won't want to delete it.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield The question may have been a joke to you, but it's actually an ongoing discussion with fans (apparently). It's been asked elsewhere, just not on SF.SE.

Comment: @CreationEdge i know it's a hot topic among fans, but that's mostly because they don't understand language. There are two possible ways to pluralize "horcrux" in English - "horcruces" and "horcruxes", the latter of which JKR used within the books. So that really should be the end of the debate.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield "-ux" and "-us" sound sufficiently similar in English that "horcri" was also my first thought (perhaps "horcry" with a pun using the word "cry").  I've never liked "-uxes" (because of the "s" sound within "x") and in this case "-uces" also sounds odd to me but I can't place why

Comment: cruces sounds wierd because we don't have a ton of -ux loan words in English, but the rules are the same for the -ix loan words: index -> indices, appendix -> appendices.

Comment: There's a chapter in HBP called Horcruxes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's a good question. JKR herself doesn't seem to know:

> **JKR:** *And did you like the dedication? "You were right all along about 'Horcri'?"*
>
> **SU:** *Oh, no!*
>
> **MA:** *Oh, Jo!*
>
> **SU:** *There's that word!*
>
> **JN:** *Nobody would believe me.*
>
> **MA:** *Oh, he's never gonna let us--*
>
> **JKR:** *So, I did write him a letter. And I did say that, actually, "horcri" is-- I mean, it occurred to me, you know, it really would've
>   been, I think, a more correct plural, but I already had "inferi", and
>   I didn't wanna have too many, umm, you know, Dark Arts weapons ending
>   in "R I", so it was a kind of stylistic choice, really. I like
>   "horcruxes" as a plural.* - <sub>[Pottercast Interview : Part 1, 2007-12-17](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1217-pottercast-anelli.html)</sub>

and

> **JN:** *Until next time, guys, keep twiddling those dials.*
>
> **JKR:** *The next password will be: "Horcri".* <sub>[Pottercast Interview : Part 2, 2007-12-24](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1224-pottercast-anelli.html)</sub>

However, on her [old website](http://web.archive.org/web/20070209060508/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=113) she explicity stated that it was Horcrux**es**. This page was first archived on 2006-06-12, and last archived on 2011-08-06.

> **Q. Is the plural of 'Horcrux' 'Horcri?'**
>
> **A.** *No, **the plural of 'Horcrux' is 'Horcruxes**', as demonstrated by the eponymous chapter in 'Half-Blood Prince.'*